# How to change add and remove active class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have navigation Bar where I want to add active class and remove it from a previous clicked list I think it's a basic thing but I'm new in javascript so i couldn't figure out the solution. I have code that works but the last and first list does not remove.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="icon-layout">
      <ul>
         <li>CLOTHING</li>
         <li>BAGS</li>
         <li>SHOES</li>
         <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
         <li>BEAUTY</li>
         <li>ABOUT US</li>
         <li>SERVICE</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#icon-layout .active{
  background-color: #FF4136;
  color: white;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var activeclass = document.querySelectorAll('#icon-layout li');
   for (var i = 0; i < activeclass.length; i++) {
    activeclass[i].addEventListener('click', activateClass);
   }
function activateClass(e) {
    var previous = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    var next = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    previous.classList.remove('active');
    next.classList.remove('active');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var activeclass = document.querySelectorAll('#icon-layout li');
   for (var i = 0; i < activeclass.length; i++) {
    activeclass[i].addEventListener('click', activateClass);
   }
function activateClass(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < activeclass.length; i++) {
        activeclass[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    e.target.classList.add('active');
}
```

You may loop through all elements and remove class before adding one

Answer (score 2):

Try using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) as it would definitely make your task easier:

```
$('#icon-layout li').on('click', function() {
    $('.icon-layout li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```